# Why is my frontend code behaving differently locally versus production?

Tags: vue.js, heroku, bootstrap-vue

Currently just a BootstrapVue VueJS frontend project I have, I have 4 playing cards that I would ideally like to keep on one line/row (as it does locally), but stacks when I view it in production (using Heroku, if it makes a difference)

[image: Localhost vs Production]

Currently the code for this is like:

```
    <div 
        flex-wrap="nowrap" 
        class="row d-flex nowrap mt-3" 
        justify-content="space-between" 
        width="100vw"
    >
        <b-container>
            <b-row>
                <b-col>
                    <PlayingCard/>
                </b-col>
                ....etc for the other cards....
             </b-row>
        </b-container>
    </div>
```

I've played around a lot with different classes and justify-contents and all that stuff, but continually get different local vs prod results. And I can confirm the code on Heroku is up to date because it redeploys with each new commit and I've added some new features since attempting to fix this styling issue and those appear properly.

Comment: Can be a browser cache issue. Did you try to load the prod site with cache disabled (use Dev Tools for that) ?

Comment: OP, can you provide the link to the website so I can inspect it?

Answer (score 5):

Styling issues like that are most commonly due to scoping issues of your CSS. If you inspect the element locally you will likely see that only the local styling has been applied, while if you inspect the element in production, you will see that either the selector contains more CSS (due to identical selectors in two different components), or another selector is applied altogether.

You are getting this problem, because in dev-mode it only loads the CSS of the components you are viewing. In production mode, all the CSS of all components is combined.

To solve the problem, you have several options:

1. You can use the `scoped` attribute on your style tag. Vue will automatically add a data-attribute on your component, and scope the styling using that data attribute. This does commonly not work nicely with things like popups that are moved out of their previous location.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- something here -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  //...
}
</script>

<style scoped>
button {
  // This only styles the buttons in this component, rather than every button in the application
}
</style>
```

2. If you need to style sub-components as well, you can just use a class on your root element and style everything relative to that. You would need to make that class a unique name in your application, but if you just use the name of your component that shouldn't be a problem.

```
<template>
  <div class="comp-card">
    <!-- something here -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Card'
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.comp-card {
  button {
    // All buttons that are descendants of our component are now styled.
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: So I went with the scoped route and moved my code into there, fixed the 'invalid property value' errors I was getting on the scoped styling. Local vs prod looks to be the exact same at this point from my point of view, however I'm still having the exact same issue.

The only 'flex-wrap' value that exists within the code is for the scoped styling of nowrap, which is what I want, but production still fails to behave as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues with the given code, addressing these may not resolve your issue, but may remove some interference.

1. Bootstrap [provides the class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/#wrap) `.flex-nowrap` for applying `flex: nowrap` – it should be noted that `nowrap` is the default behaviour of flexbox, and this may not be needed anyway.
2. Some attributes in your `div` appear to be style declarations, and ought to be in the `[style]` attribute as shown below, or a [`<style>` tag if using SFCs](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html)

```
<div 
  class="row d-flex mt-3"
  style="justify-content: space-between; width: 100vw"
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Caching of applicable files can vary between local and production environments.

Browsers accessing production servers may cache older versions of files and make it appear that the change was not made. The server may have newer files than what the browser is using.

Answer (score 0):

UI changes in production might be issue of CSS Optimization in **build** process of vue cli.

Did you try to serve/run build locally if it works then it might issue on production site/cache/browser etc. Try local build with **serve** or any other tool to verify.

If  css optimization issue in build then re-configure build config with underlying tool like webpack or vite etc whichever used.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).